# Bluefish Editor error:failed to create a command

Tags: html, bluefish

Bluefish Editor shows this error:

```
Failed to create a command for firefox -remote 'openURL(%p)' || firefox '%p'&.
```

Whenever I want to test my  HTML code, I click to the browser button in Bluefish Editor.But it doesn't show any output on the Firefox.

My question is,how to create command for Firefox in order to test HTML code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to "Tools"->"preferences"->"External Commands"/

First make sure `firefox` is listed.
You can then try changing it's command to `firefox "%s"` or if that doesn't work change it to `firefox "%p"`

Apply and try previewing the file via the browser.

**source:** http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1584013